# Format string, integer with leading zeros

Tags: objective-c, string, formatting

I want to convert an integer value to a string with leading zeroes (if necessary) such that the string has 3 total characters. For example, `5` would become `"005"`, and `10` would become `"010"`.

I've tried this code:

```
NSString* strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img_00%d.jpg", i];
```

This partially works, but if `i` has the value of `10`, for example, the result is `img_0010.jpg`, not `img_010.jpg`.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Use the format string `"img_%03d.jpg"` to get decimal numbers with three digits and leading zeros.

Comment: To clarify: The "3" can be replaced with any number to have that total count of digits in the displayed value. For example, `%06d` would result in values like `000001`.

Answer (score 5):

For posterity: this works with decimal numbers.

```
NSString *nmbrStr = @"0033620340000" ;
NSDecimalNumber *theNum = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:nmbrStr]decimalNumberByAdding: [NSDecimalNumber one]] ;     
NSString *fmtStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%012.0F",[theNum doubleValue]] ;
```

Though this information is hard to find, it is actually documented here in the second paragraph under Formatting Basics.  Look for the % character.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html

Comment: Note here that the "12" in `@"%012.0F"` refers to the number of total digits, so including the decimal point and anything to the right.

Comment: To add to bcattle's comment, this also includes anything to the *right* as well.  To display -012.34, you'd have to use `@"%07.2f"`