# How to Format String with space for single digit numbers?

Tags: objective-c, printf

I am displaying a string to the user while uploading a video which says something like

```
20% uploaded
```

So when the percentage number is single-digit I would like the space for ten's place to be filled by a white space character.

Like How we show  01,02,03 for single - digits as a solution many times, I would like to show white space instead of that 0.

Comment: i dont get your question. Isn't this as simple as putting a whitespace instead of `0` in while displaying download percentage ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985170/format-string-integer-with-leading-zeros

Comment: @SrikarAppal: I was thinking of using a format string if there is one.

Comment: @CRDave: I wanted spaces not 0's.

Comment: Than what's the big deal replace 0 with space. If u want A than replace with A. You can put any char at that place.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar: Why don't you read all the comments, 12 minutues ago, i gave the answer.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: modifiable_value has given a simpler answer. but Thanks for your help

Comment: most welcome. I see all answer are same :)

Comment: @CRDave: What I wanted to ask was. There is particular string format to automatically show 0s on left for single digit os to fill the space for missing digits if your epecting a 3 digit or 2 digit number so that alignment is proper.
I wanted to know if there is a way I can provide a format so that I get spaces just like we get 0s in the format.
Look at modifiable lvalue's answer.
Thats what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The best idea I can think of is to check the value. If it's less than 10, print a whitespace character. You could use `%.*s` to incorporate this into printf: `printf("%.*s%d%% uploaded", value < 10, " ", value);`</strike>

**EDIT:** It appears, by the specification, that the field width `*` (or a decimal integer) does this for you: `printf("%*d%% uploaded", 2, value);` (or `printf("%02d%% uploaded", 2, value);`)

Comment: What when 100%, alignment will be lost.

Comment: in my case, I dont show 100% at all, once the upload is done I show the time since video was uploaded which is "Just Now" instead of 100%.

So only while the upload is going on I need to show percentage which wont exceed 2 digits.
and even if it does I can keep space for 3 digits instead of 2.

Like this:

printf("%*d%% uploaded", 3, value)

Alignment will always be there.

Answer (score 3):

modifiable lvalue's answer is proper to get preferred space between % and digit . YOu just have to check the value , and accordingly locate the "%" sign.
Or There is another way .

e.g. I am displaying % sign using following format.

> [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%% of 100%
>   uploaded..",progressValue*10];

This accordingly manages space between your value and '%' sign.

Comment: I didn't get the alignment by trying this method. Also, `100%` should be `100%%`.

Comment: Yes It was my mistake , there should be 100%% . But I am able to manage the space between digit n % sign using '.0f' format.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do by setting the format to `%<alighmentInteger>d`

You can store the value into a `stringWithFormat:`

Only for showing I am directly NSLogging.

```
    NSLog(@"%3d%%",i); //this will pad 3 white spaces.
```

If you want 2 white spaces use `2d`

E.g.:

```
for (int i=0; i<101; i+=25) {
    NSLog(@"%3d%% uploaded",i);
}
```

Output:

```
2013-04-16 11:55:16.002 DynamicObject[48056:303]   0% uploaded
2013-04-16 11:55:16.003 DynamicObject[48056:303]  25% uploaded
2013-04-16 11:55:16.003 DynamicObject[48056:303]  50% uploaded
2013-04-16 11:55:16.004 DynamicObject[48056:303]  75% uploaded
2013-04-16 11:55:16.004 DynamicObject[48056:303] 100% uploaded
```

Comment: Much effective solution than my answer; didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: @tolgamorf: even your answer is same as mine. I posted this in comment 11 minutes ago, and waited no one gave correct answer, so i finally posted it here.

Comment: By that time I was working on it, so didn't see your comment. :) Now that I think of it, in my answer, the alignment would be lost when the progress is `100%`.

Comment: Your answer also works but I can mark only one as correct.
You specify 3 or 2 in the format he did it as argument.

I slightly prefer the other approach as number of digits is a parameter which can be controlled better :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method which returns the desired output

```
- (NSString *)uploadProgress:(NSUInteger)progress {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%% uploaded", progress < 10 ?
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %i", progress] :
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", progress]];
}
```

Call:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self uploadProgress:5]);
NSLog(@"%@", [self uploadProgress:50]);
```

Output:

```
2013-04-16 02:24:49.948 stackoverflow test001[11587:c07]  5% uploaded
2013-04-16 02:24:49.949 stackoverflow test001[11587:c07] 50% uploaded
```